# problem similar to Erdos-Straus problem

Tags: number-theory

Given $n > 1$ integer, is it possible to always write $\frac{3}{n}= \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{1}{2c}$ where $a,b,c$ integers ?

I checked it for the first few hunder numbers and i found solution.

It look similar to erdos problem but i think its much simpler.

I proved it to all number except for numbers of the form $12 k+1$.

Is there an elemnatry soultion to the problem.

Comment: How did you prove it for $n=12k-5$? I haven't found any which can't be represented at all, but for some of them the search for a representation is quite long, e.g. 127, 631, 35911.

Comment: Ah, never mind. $n=12k-5\implies 6/n=12k/2kn=(n+4+1)/2kn=1/2k+2/kn+1/2kn$ so $3/n=1/kn+1/4k+1/4kn$.

Comment: For every prime $n<10000$, $n=12k+1$, there is at least one solution. As with the Erdos-Straus conjecture, and more especially with its $6/n$ variant, there is no elementary solution. That's not to say that it can't be solved, only that it won't be easy.